# Regular expression to modify a line that contains only a single word at the start

Tags: regex

I have a text file in which any line that starts with a single word and has no other characters after that should be enclosed inside caret characters.

For example, a line that contains only the following 6 characters (plus the newline):

```
France
```

should be replaced with a line that consists of only the following 8 characters (plus the newline):

```
^France^
```

Is there a Regular Expression I could use in the Find/Replace feature of my text editor (Jedit) to make these modifications to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex to find lines with a single word:

```
^(\w+)$
```

replace with:

```
^$1^
```

Comment: I ended up with only the ^^ characters on those lines - the text on those lines was erased.

Comment: I edited a few seconds after the original post and added `()` - does it still erase your line?

Comment: Yes, thanks, now it makes the replacement correctly but adds two extra blank lines after each of those lines where there is a match. Is that avoidable?

Comment: That is strange... It isn't matching any newlines. Maybe your `replace` has extra lines?

Comment: Damn. Yeah, I just noticed there were extra newline characters that I couldn't see. Sorry. This works perfectly. Thanks a lot!!